# Does this game make you arbitrarily rich with probability one?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

We toss a coin. If it's heads we win $\$ 1$, otherwise we lose $ \$ 1$. Fix some large sum. Will we be winning this amount with probability one at some point? We assume that we have infinitely many throws and an infinite amount of money.

More formally (please correct me if if there are errors). Consider the following Markov process: $$X_{i+1} = X_{i}+d_i,$$
where each $d_i$ is a random variable taking values 1 and -1 with an equal probability (if $i \neq j$ $d_i$ and $d_j$ are independent). Let $M \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and define a Markov time $$\tau_M = \min \left\{ i \: \middle| \: X_i = M \right\}.$$

Is it true that $$ P(\tau_M < \infty ) = 1$$
for all $M$?

I'd guess it's true and that there is a simple proof. Are there some canonical ways of dealing with these type of questions? Not a homework, something I just thought about.

Comment: I checked the definition and it seems that stopping time should be almost surely finite. So my question could be stated as: "Does $\tau_M$ qualify as a stopping time?"

Comment: It's true. The idea of a proof for this and many related problems is to replace your "stopping time" (which strictly speaking should be called a Markov time, until you know the property you want to prove) with the time to hit the boundary of $[-N,M]$ for positive integers $N$. Then you send $N \to \infty$ and see what happens to the distribution of this new Markov time when you do that.

Comment: By the way, if you look for resources about the optional stopping theorem, you will see plenty of examples of this character worked out. That's because a small variant of this (where instead of always betting a dollar, you double your bet every time you lose) creates the classic "counterexample" to the optional stopping theorem. (Basically, the optional stopping theorem says that under some conditions, a "fair game" is actually fair, in the sense that you cannot win on average regardless of strategy. Being able to go into arbitrary debt is one way to violate these conditions.)

Comment: how much richer than 'infinitely rich' can you be? and in theory it also makes you arbitrarily poor with probability 1.

Comment: Well you could replace it by "will your profits be arbitrarly large?". It's loosely stated, true, but the point was to quickly explain the idea. :)

Comment: Yes, the simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb Z$ is recurrent. You are guaranteed to eventually visit every state.

Answer (score 0):

Let we say that a sequence of $2n$ throws is *balanced* if at any point we are not winning any dollar, but with the last throw we are losing zero. It is well-known that the number of balanced sequences of length $2n$ is given by the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):
$$ C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}. $$
If we say that a sequence of $2n$ throws is *returning* if at any point we are losing a positive amount of dollars, but with the last throw we are losing zero, then the number of returning sequences of length $2n$ is given by:
$$ R_n = \frac{1}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1} \geq \frac{2^{2n}}{4\sqrt{\pi} \left(n-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3/2}},$$
so the probability to be winning $k$ dollars at some time is greater than:
$$ \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{4\sqrt{\pi}\left(n-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3/2}}\geq \frac{13}{28\cdot 2^k}.$$
Since $$\sum_{n\geq 1}R_n z^n = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}$$
by evaluating the RHS at $z=\frac{1}{4}$ we have that any losing streak ends with probability $1$, as well as any winning streak. That gives that we go back to the original configuration with probability $1$, so the "zero money" state is a recurring state for our random walk, as well as any other state, since the probability that we may go on playing forever without winning or losing more than $k$ dollars is clearly zero.